# Standard ASP.NET WebAPI way to return negotiated text/html response (Razor)

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-web-api

I'm prototyping a system using ASP.NET MVC 5 and/or WebAPI. We need to create services which can return results differently based on negotiated content type from the client.

e.g. if the client requests text/html, we want to return a normal HTML web page rendered using Razor, but if the client requests JSON, we should return a restful resource representation.

I see there is a webapi contrib project that appears to support this scenario ( https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Razor ) but i'm wondering: is there a standard ASP.NET out-of-the-box way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty easy in standard MVC.  Consider a controller action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel request)
{
    // based on the request, return a response
}
```

That action can return any `ActionResult`, doesn't matter which one.  So in one code path you may have:

```
return View(someViewModel);
```

while in another you may have:

```
return Json(someViewModel);
```

The first one would pass control to the view which would use Razor and return a web page as normal, the second would just return a JSON response with the serialized data.

How you determine that code path is up to you, but as you say this can be done with header-based content negotiation.  You *could* examine the headers directly in the controller, but that risks coupling the controller to the HTTP Context which isn't great for testing.

If there are going to be numerous such actions, perhaps an elegant way to achieve this would be to add a custom model binder to the MVC pipeline which itself examines the header information and just passes it to the controller.

So your controller action(s) may simply get another parameter:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(HeaderInfo headers, SomeModel request)
{
    // based on the values in "headers", return a response
}
```

`HeaderInfo` can just be a simple custom class, which may even just have a single boolean on it for starters:

```
public class HeaderInfo
{
    public bool ReturnDataOnly { get; set; }
}
```

Based on the state of that boolean, the controller returns the whole view or just the data (JSON).  You can then inject a custom model binder into the pipeline to automatically bind this for all requests which include it.  That binder could be as simple as this:

```
public class HeaderInfoBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

        var result = new HeaderInfo();
        // examine the contexts for headers, based on those headers
        //   set true or false on the object's property

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then add it to the MVC configuration bootstrappers (usually in `App_Start`):

```
public class BinderConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBinders(ModelBinderDictionary binders)
    {
        binders[typeof(HeaderInfo)] = new HeaderInfoBinder();
    }
}
```

And call that config from application start in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
BinderConfig.RegisterBinders(ModelBinders.Binders); // <-- right there
```

With those few tweaks, any controller action anywhere in the application which has a `HeaderInfo` parameter would automatically have that parameter populated at runtime based on the logic in that `HeaderInfoBinder`, which you can tweak and add to as you see fit.  Then any controller action can just examine that object to determine what to return.  (Which may result in a lot of repeated `switch` blocks, which you can probably further refactor into a generic helper somewhere.)

Comment: wow! Nice answer. If I switch to MVC doesn't that mean that I lose the WebAPI benefits of eg IContentNegotiator, verb based routing conventions, OAuth authentication etc? Conceptually we view this as an API rather than a "web application" (in the normal asp.net sense of that word.)

Comment: @goofballLogic: Similar capabilities exist in WebAPI. For the custom binder, for example, you can write something similar (different base classes and different configuration bootstrap though) and use a parameter attribute to tell the WebAPI methods to use that binder.  *Supposedly* the new (next?) version combines MVC and WebAPI in much more elegant ways, whereas traditionally the two have had somewhat separate though quite similar framework pipelines. I'm not sure if that means it'll be easy to have WebAPI return a view, I've never done that before. All the concepts should be the same though.